# c# cache control for .jpg, .css, .js...

Tags: c#, caching, browser-cache

I analyzed my website, and appear this error "No expiration time specified" for files .css, .js, .png, .jpg, etc.

I've found this for php

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
<FilesMatch "\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|swf|js|css|swf)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public"
</FilesMatch>
```

What is the equivalence in C#? and, should I code this in web.config?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set `clientCache` in `staticContent` block of your IIS Config.

```
<system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="30.00:00:00" />
    </staticContent>
  </system.webServer>
```

This sets the expiry for 30 days.

Detailed explaination can be found [here](https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/staticcontent/clientcache).

Comment: Thank you very much, This work fine! @NutcaseDeveloper